# Modify Word Document Multilevel list to include all depth

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that has a 4 level deep multilevel list. I would like to modify the list styles (temporarily) to show the entire depth of the numbers. For instance, rather than just showing (iii), I want to modify it to show 1.1(a)(iii). I have seen instructions of attaching the style to the list, but I'm not sure how to write the style to show what I want.

So, all of the searching and the replies have not resulted in a working solution, yet, but I did discover that the .docx file is a zipped collection of xml files. So, after looking inside the docx file and the numbering.xml sub-file, I found the following section that seems to define the style for the numbering I am looking to change:

```
<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="93" w15:restartNumberingAfterBreak="0">
<w:nsid w:val="5FE75E67"/>
<w:multiLevelType w:val="multilevel"/>
<w:tmpl w:val="9C366D9C"/>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL1"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="%1"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="720"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps/>
        <w:smallCaps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="1">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL2"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="%1.%2"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="720"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="2">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL3"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="(%3)"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="720"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="3">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL4"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="(%4)"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="1440"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="1440" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="4">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL5"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="%5."/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="2160"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="2160" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="5">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL6"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="%6."/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="2160"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="2160" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Times New Roman" w:hint="default"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="6">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/>
    <w:lvlRestart w:val="0"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL7"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="·"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="1440"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="1440" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="7">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/>
    <w:lvlRestart w:val="0"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL8"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="·"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="2160"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="2160" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
<w:lvl w:ilvl="8">
    <w:start w:val="1"/>
    <w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL9"/>
    <w:lvlText w:val="·"/>
    <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="2880"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:ind w:left="2880" w:hanging="720"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
        <w:b w:val="0"/>
        <w:i w:val="0"/>
        <w:caps w:val="0"/>
        <w:color w:val="auto"/>
        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
        <w:u w:val="none"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
```

Hopefully, this means that I can change the w:lvlText w:val="(%3) for w:ilvl="2" using VBA. Still investigating.

Thanks!
Rod

Comment: Do you specifically want VBA code for this? Or would changing it in the UI be enough? Note that the simplest way to get the code you need would be to record a macro while making the change in the UI.

Comment: I am specifically looking for the VBA code. I would settle for just the basics of getting to the options. I'm fairly good at working through the MSDN object tree but I'm not that familiar with the entire MS Word setup. I'm a LibreOffice user for the most part. This is for a new project I've been asked to work on.

Comment: Also, for reference the following did not work:
wDoc.ListTemplates("ArticleC_L3").ListLevels(3).NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3"

I am currently trying wDoc.Styles("ArticleC_L3").Font.Bold=True to see if I can even touch the style.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add more information directly TO the question. Code, especially, is difficult to read in a comment. Also note that you should explicilty "ping" someone if answer them. For example: @RodNaughler. You'll get pinged automatically when we post a comments, but we won't when you answer...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that you can, indeed, directly modify a multiLevelList style at any level if you know how to refer to it. Using the xml file I referenced, I found that the third level style, ArticleC_L3, had it's number format set to "(%3)" which is what I wanted to change. It was in an abstract with AbstractNumId="93". The following code changes that setting:

```
wDoc.ListTemplates(94).ListLevels(3).NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3"
```

You will notice that the ListTemplates number is one higher, and the ListLevels ID is likewise one higher. In either case, to find the precise place you need to refer to, the best workflow I have found is:
 1. In the word doc, click on the number/bullet for the level you are trying to change.
 2. Click the little dropdown arrow in the styles box so you can see what the style name is for that level.
 3. Look in numbering.xml to see which number style is using that style name. For me the line read `<w:pStyle w:val="ArticleCL3"/>` 
 4. Follow the xml tree up to find out what level of the numbering style this is. For me the line read `<w:lvl w:ilvl="2">` 
 5. Continue to follow the xml tree up to find out what Template number the level is in. For me the line read `<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="93" w15:restartNumberingAfterBreak="0">` 
 6. Now you can refer to the exact level format as in the line I shared at the start.

Thanks for eveyone's help!
Rod

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, something based on:

```
Sub ApplyMultiLevelStyleNumbers()
Dim LT As ListTemplate, i As Long
Set LT = ActiveDocument.ListTemplates.Add(OutlineNumbered:=True)
For i = 1 To 4
  With LT.ListLevels(i)
    .NumberFormat = Choose(i, "%1", "%1.%2", "%1.%2.%3", "%1.%2.%3.%4")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .ResetOnHigher = True
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = "ArticleC_L" & i
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

The above assumes your four styles are named ArticleC_L1 - ArticleC_L4.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, to no effect. I am assuming that there is already a definition for the list styles ArticleC_L1 through L9. I can see them in the styles browser and they highlight as I click on different number levels. However, I'm stuck trying to find where they are in the document tree.
Is there a Word document object browser?